# iOS application first run setup GUI

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app is a 5 tabviewcontroller app.

I want to build a first run set up routine that will collect info from the user in five steps (5 UIViews).

This GUI should hide my entire application GUI during the set up, in a similar way that happens when you restore an iPhone and have it set up for wi-fi, iCloud, etc...

I am trying

```
[self presentViewController:firstRunSetUp_1_ViewController animated:YES completion:NULL]
```

But this does not allow me to push the following view controllers.

UPDATE:

This is my code in appDidFinishLauching in appDelegate:

```
BHfirstRunSetUp_1_ViewController *f = [[BHfirstRunSetUp_1_ViewController alloc]init];

[self.myTabBarController.selectedViewController presentViewController:f animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

This is code inside "nextButtonClicked" IBAction, inside the BHfirstRunSetUp_1:

```
-(IBAction)nextButtonClicked:(id)sender

{
NSLog(@"inside nextButton clicked...");

// initialize second view controller:

if (firstRunSetUp_2_ViewController == nil) {

     firstRunSetUp_2_ViewController = [[BHfirstRunSepUp_2_ViewController alloc]init];

}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:firstRunSetUp_2_ViewController animated:YES];

}
```

I have these lines in console:

2013-08-01 20:20:33.106 iNota[3245:907] inside nextButton clicked...

But the view isn't pushed!

Here is a screen shot:

http://www.idanfe.com/images/1.png "screenshot"

+++ UPDATE 2 ++++

I have taken Apple's Tabster example and changed it, adding my lines. You find a copy here:

http://www.idanfe.com/sample/Tabster.zip "Tabster"

Comment: you can always push a UINavigationController...

Answer (score 2):

Push a UINavigationController.  eg:

```
UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstRunSetUp_1_ViewController];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, This works for the first step of the setup, but if I "present" the next viewController for step 2, it just puts another view on top of the previous, and I would like to have a "push" effect. And then "push" doe not work.

Comment: from your setup view controllers call `[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];`.

Answer (score 0):

You can push them into section using as a modal view, but suggestion is to use uinavigationviewcontroller which is a rootviewcontroller in window ( in app delegate ).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking for, just present a navigation controller in the first step, which will show the root view controller of that navigate controller. Then push to your other 4 setup controllers. When you're done, dismiss the navigation controller.